# How to find specific url of newly created category in Hybris PCM

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Hi whenever i try to create the new product category in hybris product cockpit 
i create the identifier, name and the correct catalog version which is Online

but when i try to edit the navigation of the website im currently lost where do i find the url of that specific category so when the user click on that navigation it will filter on which category of the product is tagged

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this does not appear to be a programming question at all.

Comment: The mapping in CategoryPageController is `/**/c` + the path variable with `categoryCode` so by default you can access your category by entering `<whatever>/c/{categoryCode}`

Comment: @qwerty1423 thanks for this answer, basically what i did is to remember the identifier of the category and the category name itself thanks for this again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If your navigation menu is composed of **CMSLinkComponent**s you are lucky, because CMSLinkComponent was already made to handle this, you have just to :

  1. create a new CMSLinkComponent.
  2. Attach the new create Category to the CMSLinkComponent.
  3. Then add this CMSLinkComponent to your navigation menu. (that's all what you need to do).

[image]

- However if you don't use CMSLinkComponent, you can use the `defaultCategoryModelUrlResolver.resolve(newCategory)` to generate the URL of the category and then send it back to the Front to be printed.
- Or just print it like this in your jsp file :

  `<c:url var="categoryUrl" value="/c/${newCategory.code}" /> 
   <a href="${categoryUrl}">${newCategory.name}</a>`

Comment: Thank you for this answer. currently what i did is to remember the identifier of the category <name of the category>/c/<category identifier>